# How to log to GKE StackDriver using winston logger?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, winston

I'm following [this](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/nodejs) instructions to add winston logger to my node backend app.

It is currently running on `GKE` and normal `console.log` does show up in `stackdriver`.
Though, using winston logger doesn't display the logs.

I have just set up the logger like this:

```
export const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level,
  format: winston.format.simple(),
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({
      handleExceptions: true,
    }),
    new LoggingWinston(),
  ],
  exitOnError: false,
});
```

I don't need it to log from my local machine, is there anything else I need to configure?

Comment: Your code shows setting up Winston, but not actually using it. Logs will not show up in Stackdriver until you write log entries. I do not understand your last sentence (I don't need it to log from my local machine ...)

Comment: Hi I do use the logger for logging.. it just says in the docs `logging from local machine` which I didn't understand why would someone use it... Am I missing some configuration or does it should work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the following code you've provided, you did not add the following lines such as:

(logger.error),
(logger.info).

These would essential to write the log entries which @JohnHanley had mentioned earlier. Notice that in the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/nodejs#using_winston) that you mentioned, those two lines were also included.